# Foundation Wall out of alignment

Tags: walls, foundation

The foundation wall of our house is cinder block with concrete (maybe cement not sure) over
it. It has a couple of over small cracks in it. You can see the outline of the cinder blocks in the wall.

Using a laser level, a contractor has determined that the wall is 1/8
of an inch over 20 feet not level in the vertical direction. He says this is a sign that the wall has shifted and he is talking about major repairs to fix the problem.

My view is that we do not have any real problem. Something to watch carefully but that is all.  Is my plan for the issue a good one?

Comment: You did not directly ask any question.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Now I did ask a question.

Comment: What was the measurement when built, is the question to ask the contractor.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a photo? (You can see the outline of the cinder blocks in the wall.)

Comment: I am not planning on posting a photo.

Comment: @crip659 The house is over 60 years old. I think the  contractor is out of business.

Comment: 1/8" out of plumb?  That is well within rough forming expectations.  How thick are the cracks?  Less than 1/8" wide I wouldn't be concerned but I'd likely do as you say and just monitor.

Comment: Why did you have a contractor looking at it?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I was looking for a contractor to repair two outside cracks. I was thinking it was/is a simple repair. Something like you put epoxy or cement into the cracks. It want to look in the basement to find what he  considered to be an issue.

Comment: The width of the crack is about 0.0689 inches; the thickness of a quarter.

Comment: Settlement of 1/8" over 20' in 60 years seems like small potatoes to me, and something I would simply monitor over the next 60 years.

Answer (score 3):

Impossible to say without detail not provided. 1/8" over 20 feet might have been there from new, happened over 60 years, or happened last week. Those have different levels of concern.

If it was level last week, or last month, or even last year, that's a big deal. Otherwise, not so much.

You might look into a reinforced surface-bonding stucco product for the "cracks between blocks" issue, but if there's a sinkhole opening under the foundation footing that won't do much for you.

Comment: I have no way of knowing when the wall came out of alignment. About 9 months ago, a PE was here (for a cracked joist issue) and he looked for signs of a problem with the foundation but did not find any

Answer (score 2):

> The foundation wall of our house is cinder block with concrete (maybe cement not sure) over it. It has a couple of over small cracks in it. You can see the outline of the cinder blocks in the wall.

This sounds like you are describing a block wall with stucco. If that is the case 1/8 inch over 20 feet is minimal.  The cracks could be superficial, or an issue we have no way of knowing especially without pictures.

Get a second opinion before spending money on what may be a minor cosmetic issue.